# How can access property from error object in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting large error object from my 3rd party API function. I am trying to access object property (private/protected) but can not access it, i have converted object to array and Json format but can not access it. any suggestion how can i access value from object?
below is an object.

```
ABC\Connect\Sdk\ValidationException Object
(
[httpStatusCode:ABC\Connect\Sdk\ResponseException:private] => 400
[response:ABC\Connect\Sdk\ResponseException:private] => ABC\Connect\Sdk\Domain\Errors\ErrorResponse Object
    (
        [errorId] => 66116632332b917f7fd885702174a8b0ff
        [errors] => Array
            (
                [0] => ABC\Connect\Sdk\Domain\Errors\Definitions\APIError Object
                    (
                        [category] => 
                        [code] => 221000044
                        [httpStatusCode] => 400
                        [id] => 
                        [message] => INVALID DATETIME YYYYMMDDHH24MISS: REQUESTID 417622, KEY order.customer.personalInformation.dateOfBirth, VALUE: 00000000
                        [propertyName] => customer.personalInformation.dateOfBirth
                        [requestId] => 
                    )

            )

    )
  )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the `Ingenico-ePayments/connect-sdk-php` library. You can do it like this to access the response object of the exception.

```php
try {
    // some code throwing ValidationException
} catch(ValidationException $e) {
    echo $e->getResponse();
}
```

Comment: It's working, I need to use echo $e->getResponse(); to fetch catch response. thank you Mohsen

Answer (score 1):

You can use try catch with exception handling.

```
<?php
try {
    throw new Error("Some error message");
} catch(Error $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Nope, this is not working, i need to fetch response object from above returning object.